# slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method in numpy python3

Tags: python, slice

I am trying to use the code of KD-tree and I get this type of error relating to type of number in numpy

```
File "kdtree.py", line 76, in <module>
    tree = makeKDtree(points,0) 
  File "kdtree.py", line 31, in makeKDtree
    goLeft = points[:median,:]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

The concerned line is the one with `goLeft = points[:median,:]  goRight = points[median+1:,:]` and
`tree = makeKDtree(points,0)`

```
        # Separate the remaining points
        goLeft = points[:median,:] >*where the line gets error*
        goRight = points[median+1:,:]

        # Make a new branching node and recurse
        newNode = node()
        newNode.point = points[median,:]
        newNode.left = makeKDtree(goLeft,depth+1)
        newNode.right = makeKDtree(goRight,depth+1)
        return newNode

...

points = np.array([[1,6],[2,2],[3,7],[5,4],[6,8],[6,1],[7,5]])
tree = makeKDtree(points,0) >>*where the line gets error*
print (returnNearest(tree,np.array([3,5]),0))
print (returnNearest(tree,np.array([4.5,2]),0))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include enough of the code.  What is median?

Comment: I have tried to add ```points.astype(int)``` after the ```points = np.array([[1,6],[2,2],[3,7],[5,4],[6,8],[6,1],[7,5]])``` but it didn't work.

Comment: SO didn't allow me to include all the code in the question so here it is: https://homepages.ecs.vuw.ac.nz/~marslast/Code/Ch7/kdtree.py

Comment: from your code, median is ```np.ceil(...)``` and as such, that's a float (iirc).  The problem is that index should be an Integer, so I guess you can try ```int(median)```

Comment: it's actually work. thank you sir @ewong